# Does JavaFX have loops in fxml files like angular's *ngFor?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

As we know modern web (front-end) frameworks allow us to iterate over a collection of elements and display some content based on it, for example, angular has `*ngFor` construction which allow us to do it in html template.
The question might be a bit strange, but still relevant. Does JavaFX have loops in fxml files like angular's `*ngFor` or some similar concepts which will allow us to avoid loops in controllers? I think it would be really useful to have such syntax, something like this:

somewhere in **fxml**:

```
<Label fx:forEach="String s: collection" text="${s}"/>
```

**NOTE** maybe this is exist already I just don't know about it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There's no similar construct. You could perhaps define a [custom component](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) that achieved the same idea (maybe?).

Comment: FXML isn't really analogous to say Angular.  You can however achieve these results by skipping the FXML and programmatically (imperatively) creating your UI

Comment: Go for a ListView I would say and maybe use a Custom Controller for it. But in general there is no way to include data from the Controller in the fxml anyways not even that is possible.

Comment: @Alex That last part is not true; the controller is automatically placed in the `FXMLLoader`’s namespace, so data in the controller is accessible in the FXML via `”${controller.someProperty}”`, as long as you initialize it before calling `load()`.

Comment: The [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) document relates the capabilities of JavaFX FXML.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.